# Create a JSON document, elasticsearch

Tags: json, elasticsearch, indexing, document

I will quote part of the documentation of 'www.elastic.co' concerning the creation of a JSON document:

> index a simple customer document into the customer index, "external" type, with an ID of 1 as follows :
>   Our JSON document: { "name": "John Doe" }

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/customer/external/1?pretty' -d '{"name": "John Doe"}'
```

I removed the quotes from the url,

`curl -XPUT localhost:9200/customer/external/1?pretty -d '{"name": "John Doe"}'`

the result is an error

> `{ "error" : "Content-Type header [application/x-www-formurlencoded] is not supported", "status" : 406`}

Answer (score 0):

Content type is missing in the curl query.

```
curl -XPUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" 'localhost:9200/customer/external/1?pretty' -d '{"name": "John Doe"}'
```

Comment: The result is an error : " crul (6) Could not resolve host 'localhost " and " crul (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 9 "

Comment: The result is an error : " crul (6) Could not resolve host 'localhost " and " crul (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 9 "

Comment: try this `curl -XPUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" "localhost:9200/customer/external/1?pretty" -d '{"name": "John Doe"}'`

Comment: "     {"error" : { "root_cause" : [{ "type" : "mapper_parsing_exception", "reason" : "failed to parse"}], "type" : "mapper_parsing_exception", "reason" : "failed to parse", "caused_by" : {"type" : "not_x_content_exception", "reason" : "compressor detection can only be called on some xcontent bytes or compressed xcontent bytes" } },  "status" : 400 }

Comment: Are you using curl in windows?

Comment: 1. Use " instead of ' to wrap the JSON document to be inserted
2. Mask the " within the document with \"
`curl -XPUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" "localhost:9200/customer/external/1?pretty" -d "{ \"name\": \"John Doe\"}"`

Comment: Ok, it works, it's the right syntax. Thank you very much .

Comment: Try to use kibana developer tool or postman instead of windows curl. Windows curl is not that good.

Comment: ok, i will use kibana developer tool. Thank you very much swap0129 for your precious help.

Comment: after having inserted a query into the elasticsearch search engine can we display: Index, Type and Alias for each data found?

Comment: We get _index, _type in hits of the query response. I am not sure of alias.